# How small would iron stars with a mass of 0.50 solar mass be?

Tags: stars, white-dwarfs

I am wondering how small a 0.50 solar mass iron star would be. Would they be the same size as a white dwarf of that mass which would be about the size of the Earth. Or would they be much smaller and be as small as neutron stars which would be about 10-20 kilometers in size.